# Python ООП. Класс с методами внутри

Tags: python, ооп

Прошу вашей помощи по теоретической части.
Столкнулся с реальным проектом, в котором, активно используются классы внутри которых описаны только методы, без каких-либо атрибутов. Однако мне совсем не ясен смысл таких классов.

Я написал простенький пример с "условным псевдокодом", для понимания (Я заранее извиняюсь за область примера, но мне кажется в игровой форме, я пойму это яснее:

Класс с методами:

```
class ClassWithSkills:
@classmethod
def move(cls, value):
    return print(f'Okay, i am go {value}')

@classmethod
def attack(cls, enemy):
    #Просто что-то делает, добавил для объема
    enemy_1 = [i for i in enemy]
    enemy_2 = [i for i in enemy[:-1]]
    finaly = {a:b for (a, b) in zip(enemy_1,enemy_2)}
    return print(finaly)
```

Обычный класс:

```
class Human:
    @classmethod
    def fast_move(cls, position:str):
        moving:ClassWithSkills
        return cls.moving.move(position)

    @classmethod
    def attack(cls, name:str):
        attacking:ClassWithSkills
        return cls.attacking.attack(name)

class Hero(Human):
    moving = ClassWithSkills()
    attacking = ClassWithSkills()



SomeHero = Hero()
SomeHero.fast_move("Right")
SomeHero.attack('Gena')
```

Так вот суть вопроса: Верно ли я понимаю, что создание таких классов с методами (в моём случае ClassWith Skills) позволяет мне в будущем, наполнить этот класс кучей разных "Скилов"(Методами) и в последующем "раздавать" конкретные методы их тем классам, которым они будут необходимы (в данном игровом примере:"Героям"/"Оркам" и т.д?

Есть ли ещё какой то смысл в таких классах (только с методами)?

Comment: `return print`??

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: Видимо в том, что вы не знаете что такое return.

Comment: @Эникейщик Думаю, Вы зря тут за это зацепились. Этот код приведён просто для демонстрации проблемы.